# Cloudfront second origin give wrong response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have lambda in VPC and connect gateway to it. Also I add gateway url as second origin to cloudfront and create behaviour with **/api/** path for this origin. But when I go to **https://<cloudfront_url>/api/** I get `{"message":"Not Found"}` as response. But when I go to gateway url, I get **Hello world** as response.

My lamda code is a very simple "hello world" which i use to understand how lamda works:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello world')
}
return response
```

}

My cloudfront configurations:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas about it?

Comment: Can you provide more details such as configuration or code?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams ofc. I updated my post

Comment: Does your API Gateway configuration have a resource for `/api/`? This configuration will try to access the API Gateway on this path not the root of

Comment: @ChrisWilliams. OMG. Thx a lot. It was my bad, I need to set /api* as path, not /api/. It's working now.

Comment: No problem added answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration for `/api/*` will be passing all requests to API Gateway still including the `/api/` prefix on the request.

You need to make sure your requests account for this

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I need to do - change `/api/*` path to `/api*`